# Prove that integral of a function satisfying functional inequality is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R\mapsto \Bbb R$ be a real valued function $\forall$ $x,y \in\Bbb R$ such that

$|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant|x-y|^3$

Prove that $h(x)=\int f(x)dx$ is continuous function of $x$  $\forall x \in \Bbb R$

Taking a few cases, we can remove that nasty mod. Can we integrate and remove the inequality as there is an arbitrary constant? It will be different for each x and y. I am not sure if we can do it. If we can then the problem is elementary.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: such a function $f$ is 0 everywhere.

Comment: @mookid I can think of $f(x)=constant$

Comment: you are right. do you know how to prove it?

Comment: Let me think...

Comment: try to conpute the derivative ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq |x-y|^2$ thus by taking $x\to y$ we have that $f'(y)=0$ for every $y$.Thus $f$ is constant. ...